# Problems updating flavour of linux

Tags: pdf, ubuntu, debian

*Translated from Spanish:*

Good Morning.

I have several books made with Tex (pdf made with XeLaTeX) and I have encountered a problem updating my software.

Currently I have installed texlive-full + kile. The distribution used is Debian 7.
I tried to upgrade to other distributions like Ubuntu in its flavors and other derivatives as LinuxMint, KXStudio, etc.
The result of migration has always been the same: the documents do not produce an identical pdf.
Deputy minimum tex file and pdf conducted in Debian and xBuntu / derivatives.

I make the compilation Kile with XeLaTeX
[image: Pantallazo de barra de herramientas de kile]

Does anyone know why this happens? Is there a solution?

*Untranslated Original text:*

Buenos días.

Tengo varios libros realizados con Tex (pdf hecho con xelatex) y me he encontrado con un problema al actualizar mi software.

Actualmente tengo instalado texlive-full + kile. La distribución utilizada es Debian 7.
He intentado actualizar a otras distribuciones como Ubuntu en todos sus sabores y otras derivadas como LinuxMint, KXStudio, etc.
El resultado de la migración siempre ha sido el mismo: los documentos no producen un pdf idéntico.
Adjunto el archivo mínimo de tex y los pdf realizados en Debian y xBuntu/derivados.

Hago la compilación en Kile con Xelatex

¿Alguién sabe porqué ocurre esto? ¿Tiene solución?

*File .tex:*

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book} % libro impreso
\usepackage[right=1.8cm,left=2.6cm,top=2.6cm,bottom=1.8cm,headsep=0.6cm,footskip=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} 
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setlength{\headheight}{17pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
            {6dd} %espacio entre la leyenda del capitulo y el titulo del capitulo
            {\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt} %margen izquierdo del titulo
            {-20pt} %espacio antes de la leyenda capítulo
            {3cc} %espacio despues del titulo del capitulo
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em} % entrada párrafo 1.5 cuadratines
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt} % separación entre párrafos
\linespread{1} % interlinea
\mdfdefinestyle{Marco}{%
    linecolor=black,
    outerlinewidth=0.25dd,
    roundcorner=6pt,
    innertopmargin=6dd,
    innerbottommargin=6dd,
    innerrightmargin=6dd,
    innerleftmargin=6dd,
    backgroundcolor=white}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Posiciones del paciente}

\section{Decúbito supino}

\noindent\begin{wrapfigure}[9]{l}[0mm]{54mm}
\vspace{-5mm}
\includegraphics[height=40mm, keepaspectratio]{imatges/4-1.png}
\end{wrapfigure}
\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ 
\indent 


\section{Decúbito prono}

\noindent\begin{wrapfigure}[9]{l}[0mm]{54mm}
\vspace{-5mm}
\includegraphics[height=40mm, keepaspectratio]{imatges/4-2.png}
\end{wrapfigure}
\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ 
\indent 


\section{Decúbito lateral}

\noindent\begin{wrapfigure}[9]{l}[0mm]{54mm}
\vspace{-5mm}
\includegraphics[height=40mm, keepaspectratio]{imatges/4-3.png}
\end{wrapfigure}
\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\
\indent 


\begin{mdframed}[style=Marco]

\textbf{Zonas delicadas}

\vspace{1\baselineskip}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textit{Hueco poplíteo:} Situada en la región posterior de la rodilla

\item \textit{Triángulo de Scarpa:} Espacio triangular en la región de la ingle, cuyos lados están formados por el ligamento inguinal, músculo sartorio y el primer aductor.

\item \textit{Pliegue de codo:} Zona entre el brazo y el antebrazo (parte anterior).
\end{itemize}
\end{mdframed}

\newpage

\end{document}
```

*.pdf result in Debian 7:*
[image: Versión realizada con Debian 7]

*.pdf result in xBuntu, two pages:*
[image: Versión realizada con xBuntu, página 1]

[image: Versión realizada con xBuntu, página 2]

Comment: Try adding the command `\listfiles` to your preamble, just to check the versions of style files.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thanks @Koji ! Yes there are significant changes in log files.
There are 18 major changes.
One is the md-frame-1.mdf file.
How I can do to install the Debian version (v1.5) in Ubuntu (actually v1.9b)?

Comment: @Raül: Quick and dirty: copy every style with different versions to the folder that contains your main .tex in your ubuntu machine. Latex should look there first, before even trying looking in the system folders. You can check if that's the case using ... `\listfiles` again. Good luck!

Comment: Hello @Koji. Thanks for the help you've given me.
After seeing the documents and forms indicate me to act I have fetched more information on additional commands mdframe and put a few more commands in programming mdframed seems to have solved the problem.
Specifically, only I had to add skipbelow=0 and skipabove=0 sentences.
I will review the entire document and if I have more incidents would by solved this difference between versions. My english is poor... sorry.